# how to use kernel headers appropriately?

Tags: kernel

I wrote a very simple kernel programming source code:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/fcntl.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

static int __init(void){
    sys_open("ee.c", O_RDONLY);
```

but because kernel sources (which is really executed now) is on home folder, below errors occurred. Even though I made symbolic links like that.

```
rm -rf /usr/include/linux
rm -rf /usr/include/asm

ln -s /home/linux-2.6.21/include/linux /usr/include/linux
ln -s /home/linux-2.6.21/include/asm-i386 /usr/include/asm
```

```
In file included from /usr/include/asm/fcntl.h:1,  
             from /usr/include/linux/fcntl.h:4,  
             from v.c:2:  
/usr/include/asm-generic/fcntl.h:120: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘off_t’  
/usr/include/asm-generic/fcntl.h:143: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘loff_t’
```

What do I need to do before using kernel headers which is different folder with `/usr/include` and why this type errors occurred?

i made also

```
rm -rf /usr/include/asm
ln -s /home/linux-2.6.21/include/asm-i386 /usr/include/asm
```

and `#include <linux/syscall.h>`
i was stucked....
that is full error message.. i think the kernel header files are particulary   disinformationed..

```
In file included from /usr/include/linux/syscalls.h:61,
                 from vv.c:4:
/usr/include/linux/list.h:959:2: warning: #warning "don't include kernel headers in userspace"
In file included from /usr/include/asm/siginfo.h:4,
                 from /usr/include/linux/syscalls.h:64,
                 from vv.c:4:
/usr/include/asm-generic/siginfo.h:75: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘clock_t’
In file included from /usr/include/asm/signal.h:5,
                 from /usr/include/linux/syscalls.h:65,
                 from vv.c:4:
/usr/include/linux/time.h:12: error: redefinition of ‘struct timespec’
/usr/include/linux/time.h:18: error: redefinition of ‘struct timeval’
In file included from /usr/include/linux/syscalls.h:65,
                 from vv.c:4:
/usr/include/asm/signal.h:32: error: conflicting types for ‘sigset_t’
/usr/include/sys/select.h:38: error: previous declaration of ‘sigset_t’ was here
In file included from /usr/include/linux/syscalls.h:66,
                 from vv.c:4:
/usr/include/linux/quota.h:47: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘dq_data_lock’
In file included from /usr/include/asm/processor.h:17,
                 from /usr/include/asm/atomic.h:5,
                 from /usr/include/linux/key.h:22,
                 from /usr/include/linux/syscalls.h:67,
                 from vv.c:4:
/usr/include/asm/msr.h:90: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘u32’
/usr/include/asm/msr.h:90: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘u32’
/usr/include/asm/msr.h:90: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘u32’
/usr/include/asm/msr.h: In function ‘rdmsr_on_cpu’:
/usr/include/asm/msr.h:92: error: ‘l’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/include/asm/msr.h:92: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/usr/include/asm/msr.h:92: error: for each function it appears in.)
/usr/include/asm/msr.h:92: error: ‘h’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/include/asm/msr.h:92: error: ‘msr_no’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/include/asm/msr.h:92: error: invalid lvalue in asm output 0
/usr/include/asm/msr.h:92: error: invalid lvalue in asm output 1
/usr/include/asm/msr.h: At top level:
/usr/include/asm/msr.h:94: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘u32’
/usr/include/asm/msr.h:94: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘u32’
/usr/include/asm/msr.h:94: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘u32’
/usr/include/asm/msr.h: In function ‘wrmsr_on_cpu’:
/usr/include/asm/msr.h:96: error: ‘msr_no’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/include/asm/msr.h:96: error: ‘l’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/include/asm/msr.h:96: error: ‘h’ undeclared (first use in this function)
In file included from /usr/include/asm/processor.h:18,
                 from /usr/include/asm/atomic.h:5,
                 from /usr/include/linux/key.h:22,
                 from /usr/include/linux/syscalls.h:67,
                 from vv.c:4:
/usr/include/asm/system.h: At top level:
/usr/include/asm/system.h:346: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘u8’
/usr/include/asm/system.h:346: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘u8’
/usr/include/asm/system.h:347: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘u16’
/usr/include/asm/system.h:347: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘u16’
/usr/include/asm/system.h:348: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘u32’
/usr/include/asm/system.h:348: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘u32’
/usr/include/asm/system.h: In function ‘cmpxchg_386’:
/usr/include/asm/system.h:355: error: too many arguments to function ‘cmpxchg_386_u8’
/usr/include/asm/system.h:357: error: too many arguments to function ‘cmpxchg_386_u16’
/usr/include/asm/system.h:359: error: too many arguments to function ‘cmpxchg_386_u32’
In file included from /usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:86,
                 from /usr/include/asm/processor.h:22,
                 from /usr/include/asm/atomic.h:5,
                 from /usr/include/linux/key.h:22,
                 from /usr/include/linux/syscalls.h:67,
                 from vv.c:4:
/usr/include/linux/bitmap.h: In function ‘bitmap_zero’:
/usr/include/linux/bitmap.h:134: error: ‘BITS_PER_LONG’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/include/linux/bitmap.h: In function ‘bitmap_fill’:
/usr/include/linux/bitmap.h:149: error: ‘BITS_PER_LONG’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/include/linux/bitmap.h: In function ‘bitmap_copy’:
/usr/include/linux/bitmap.h:155: error: ‘BITS_PER_LONG’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/include/linux/bitmap.h: In function ‘bitmap_and’:
/usr/include/linux/bitmap.h:166: error: ‘BITS_PER_LONG’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/include/linux/bitmap.h: In function ‘bitmap_or’:
/usr/include/linux/bitmap.h:175: error: ‘BITS_PER_LONG’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/include/linux/bitmap.h: In function ‘bitmap_xor’:
/usr/include/linux/bitmap.h:184: error: ‘BITS_PER_LONG’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/include/linux/bitmap.h: In function ‘bitmap_andnot’:
/usr/include/linux/bitmap.h:193: error: ‘BITS_PER_LONG’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/include/linux/bitmap.h: In function ‘bitmap_complement’:
/usr/include/linux/bitmap.h:202: error: ‘BITS_PER_LONG’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/include/linux/bitmap.h: In function ‘bitmap_equal’:
/usr/include/linux/bitmap.h:211: error: ‘BITS_PER_LONG’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/include/linux/bitmap.h: In function ‘bitmap_intersects’:
/usr/include/linux/bitmap.h:220: error: ‘BITS_PER_LONG’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/include/linux/bitmap.h: In function ‘bitmap_subset’:
/usr/include/linux/bitmap.h:229: error: ‘BITS_PER_LONG’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/include/linux/bitmap.h: In function ‘bitmap_empty’:
/usr/include/linux/bitmap.h:237: error: ‘BITS_PER_LONG’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/include/linux/bitmap.h: In function ‘bitmap_full’:
/usr/include/linux/bitmap.h:245: error: ‘BITS_PER_LONG’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/include/linux/bitmap.h: In function ‘bitmap_weight’:
/usr/include/linux/bitmap.h:253: error: ‘BITS_PER_LONG’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/include/linux/bitmap.h: In function ‘bitmap_shift_right’:
/usr/include/linux/bitmap.h:261: error: ‘BITS_PER_LONG’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/usr/include/linux/bitmap.h: In function ‘bitmap_shift_left’:
/usr/include/linux/bitmap.h:270: error: ‘BITS_PER_LONG’ undeclared (first use in this function)
In file included from /usr/include/asm/processor.h:22,
                 from /usr/include/asm/atomic.h:5,
                 from /usr/include/linux/key.h:22,
                 from /usr/include/linux/syscalls.h:67,
                 from vv.c:4:
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h: At top level:
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:88: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘DECLARE_BITMAP’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h: In function ‘__cpu_set’:
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:94: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h: In function ‘__cpu_clear’:
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:100: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h: In function ‘__cpus_setall’:
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:106: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h: In function ‘__cpus_clear’:
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:112: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h: In function ‘__cpu_test_and_set’:
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:121: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h: In function ‘__cpus_and’:
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:128: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:128: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:128: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h: In function ‘__cpus_or’:
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:135: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:135: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:135: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h: In function ‘__cpus_xor’:
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:142: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:142: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:142: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h: In function ‘__cpus_andnot’:
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:150: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:150: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:150: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h: In function ‘__cpus_complement’:
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:157: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:157: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h: In function ‘__cpus_equal’:
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:164: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:164: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h: In function ‘__cpus_intersects’:
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:171: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:171: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h: In function ‘__cpus_subset’:
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:178: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:178: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h: In function ‘__cpus_empty’:
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:184: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h: In function ‘__cpus_full’:
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:190: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h: In function ‘__cpus_weight’:
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:196: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h: In function ‘__cpus_shift_right’:
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:204: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:204: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h: In function ‘__cpus_shift_left’:
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:212: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:212: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h: In function ‘__cpumask_scnprintf’:
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:273: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h: In function ‘__cpumask_parse_user’:
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:281: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h: In function ‘__cpulist_scnprintf’:
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:289: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h: In function ‘__cpulist_parse’:
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:295: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h: In function ‘__cpu_remap’:
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:303: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:303: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h: In function ‘__cpus_remap’:
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:311: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:311: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:311: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
/usr/include/linux/cpumask.h:311: error: ‘cpumask_t’ has no member named ‘bits’
In file included from /usr/include/asm/atomic.h:5,
                 from /usr/include/linux/key.h:22,
                 from /usr/include/linux/syscalls.h:67,
                 from vv.c:4:
/usr/include/asm/processor.h: At top level:
/usr/include/asm/processor.h:82: error: ‘CONFIG_X86_L1_CACHE_SHIFT’ undeclared here (not in a function)
/usr/include/asm/processor.h:82: error: requested alignment is not a constant
In file included from vv.c:4:
/usr/include/linux/syscalls.h:114: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/linux/syscalls.h:115: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘old_sigset_t’
/usr/include/linux/syscalls.h:116: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘old_sigset_t’
/usr/include/linux/syscalls.h:178: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/linux/syscalls.h:394: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘cookie64’
/usr/include/linux/syscalls.h:474: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘mqdes’
/usr/include/linux/syscalls.h:475: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘mqdes’
/usr/include/linux/syscalls.h:476: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘mqdes’
/usr/include/linux/syscalls.h:477: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘mqdes’
/usr/include/linux/syscalls.h:507: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘key_serial_t’
/usr/include/linux/syscalls.h:512: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘key_serial_t’
/usr/include/linux/syscalls.h:546: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘u32’
/usr/include/linux/syscalls.h:547: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘u32’
vv.c: In function ‘init’:
vv.c:7: error: too few arguments to function ‘sys_open’
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `asm-generic` headers also come from the Linux kernel, so you've essentially mixed some of the sanitised headers from `/usr/include` with some from the source in your home directory.

If you are writing a user space program, you may as well just use the sanitised headers that come with the distro: the only information they are missing are the parts necessary to compile code that is intended to run inside the kernel.

To recover the files you deleted, remove the two symlinks you created and then run `apt-get install --reinstall linux-libc-dev`.

Alternatively, if you need to use unsanitised kernel headers for that particular kernel version, just pass `-I/home/linux-2.6.21/include` to the compiler so it will pick those headers in preference to the system installed ones.

Comment: the instruction   apt-get install --reinstall linux-libc-dev  is very useful! thanks! but i was stucked because of odd error messages, after making symlink and including linux/syscall.h

Comment: Okay.  `<linux/syscalls.h>` looks like it isn't intended to be included in user space code, as the "don't include kernel headers in userspace" error indicates.  The user space interface is through either the `syscall()` or `_syscall()` interfaces (both have man pages), although you may as well just use the C library wrappers: you're much less likely to make a mistake that way.

Comment: but when i search through google, i can find many codes that use <linux/syscall.h>,<linux/modules.h>... applying same kernel headers rule, how to they use kernel headers?

Comment: Presumably the code you found was kernel mode (i.e. code linked directly into the Linux kernel) rather than user mode (i.e. applications running on top of the Linux kernel).